Renouncing a contract that contains a chainlink upkeep
I am creating a contract that I want to be fully renounced, but there is also a function that needs to be called once a year in the contract. I created a chainlink upkeep to call it. The upkeep adress is the only address allowed to perform the function. I want the contract to be fully out of anyone's control Is it possible to also somehow "renounce" the upkeep so that the contract is completely safe?

You can use Forwarder to authorise the function to be called only by the Chainlink Automation/Upkeep.

The idea is great, however i'd keep a level of action even restricted.
What if in the future one address, a service or else just stops working ?
Then you cannot do anything about it. But if you have the possibility to modify the address then you can fix it.
It was just a general example , i was just emphasizing the fact that smart contracts are immutable, thus if there is a change or problem down the line it's over.
